# Rails "yield" not appearing on mobile devices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yield

In my application.html.erb, I have a layout for my site:

```
<div class="mobile-menu-navbar hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <a id="mobile-menu-link" href="#mobile-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</div>

<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  <%= render 'shared/navbar'%>
</div>

<%= yield %>
```

The first div displays the mobile menu on xs and sm screens, and the second one the desktop navbar on md and lg screens.

Below it, I have the yield method that should display the content of the page.

However, on my mobile homepage, nothing appears. When I look for my homepage's content in chrome's inspector, it is in this div:

```
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  <%= render 'shared/navbar'%>
   .......
</div>
```

Which explains why it is hidden on mobile. What I don't understand is why the yield works well on every other mobile pages (I have all my content on any other page), but not on the home page. The content is moved in the div above.

Could anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: Are you missing a closing div or anything in `shared/navbar`?

Comment: @j-dexx that's what I thought at first, but it doesn't seem to be the case. As you can see, the div hiding content on desktops screens is closed. 
And what makes it even stranger, is that on every page EXCEPT the homepage, it works well. I'm really confused

Comment: well the yield block is simply rendering whatever the controller is directing it to, so are you sure that other view is not loading the hidden div?

Comment: Please add as much of the content as needed to assist us from your "homepage action" template.

Comment: @hamitron ok you were right thank you so much. The shared/navbar div was missing a closing div tag so the closing tag of the "hidden-xs hidden-sm" became the missing closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, the shared/navbar div was missing a closing div tag so the closing tag of the "hidden-xs hidden-sm" became the missing closing tag, and was hiding the content.